# Tableau Filtering on ocurence of a String

Tags: count, filtering, tableau-api, find-occurrences

I have a Field in my Column that is filed with a String that can have a multiple occurence of the same word. Now what i want to do is to Filter this Column so that a certain Word mus occure and that only the rows show up where another word don't ocure more than one time. Here is what i get so far:

```
CONTAINS([Column1], "Santiego") AND COUNT(CONTAINS([Column1], "25")) < 2
```

The error tells me I canot mix Agregat and Non Agregat Arguments.

Is there any possibility to do this kind of filtering?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution,

In the Filter function You have to use just the Column you need and Filter with this Formula:

```
COUNT(CONTAINS([Column1], "25")) < 2
```

After that you just create a new calculation that you  put in the Filter, the calculation uses then this Formula:

```
CONTAINS([Column1], "Santiego")
```

Comment: The count() function does behave the way you are assuming it does

Comment: Actually it works but one needs to check how he put he Filter and what Fields are showed or it can give you wrong results

Comment: It may "work" but its likely by accident and very brittle. The content of the string "25" doesn't impact the result at all. Could just as well be "99" or "666". Count(<expression>) returns the number of data rows that have a non-null value for <expression>. It does not return then number of rows where <expression> is True. It does not return the sum of the values for <expression> If [Column1